# PooledConnection Issue with MultiTenancy in Grails

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, grails, groovy

I am getting a "pooled connection has already been closed" issue when I try to hit the multitenant domain 'Member' in service for the second time. I am using Grails 3.3.11 with MySQL database. I am not able to figure out what wrong am I doing.

**I have a controller defined as below -**

```
@CurrentTenant
class GroupController{
 def save(){
   groupService.getMember()
   groupService.updateMember()
 }
}
```

**I have a service defined as below -**

```
@Transactional
class GroupService{
 def getMember(){
   return Member.createCriteria().list{
     eq('customer','test')
   }
 }

 def updateMember(){
   Member.executeUpdate("Update member set group='testGroup'")
 }
}
```

**When I hit the updatemember() function I get the following error -**

```
PooledConnection has already been closed.. Stacktrace follows:
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass$ReflectionInvoker.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:211)
    at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:188)
    at org.grails.web.mapping.mvc.UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.handle(UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.groovy:90)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.UpdateRequestContextHolderExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(UpdateRequestContextHolderExceptionTranslationFilter.groovy:64)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsHttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsHttpPutFormContentFilter.groovy:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.groovy:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.deerwalk.impl.CustomCasAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(CustomCasAuthenticationFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.groovy:64)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.SecurityRequestHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityRequestHolderFilter.groovy:58)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
    at org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:77)
    at org.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:67)
    at org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter.doFilter(SingleSignOutFilter.java:97)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

**I am using multiple data sources and they have been defined as below -**

```
dataSource:
  pooled: true
  driverClassName: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
  #dbCreate: "update"
  url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/index?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&autoReconnect=true&relaxAutoCommit=true&useSSL=false
  username: root
  password: root
  properties:
    initialSize: 5
    maxActive: 100
    minIdle: 5
    maxIdle: 25
    maxWait: 10000
    maxAge: 10 * 60000
    timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 1800000
    minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 1800000
    validationQuery: "SELECT 1"
    validationInterval: 15000
    testWhileIdle: true
    testOnBorrow: true
    testOnReturn: false
    jdbcInterceptors: ConnectionState
    defaultTransactionIsolation: java.sql.Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
dataSources:
 
  shard1:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shard1?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&autoReconnect=true&relaxAutoCommit=true&useSSL=false
    dbCreate: none

  shard2:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shard2?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&autoReconnect=true&relaxAutoCommit=true&useSSL=false
    dbCreate: none
```

Answer (score 0):

Try introducing an extra layer between controller and and service.
Create a new class that would be called by the controller and add the introduce the currentTenant annotation in the new class, I had solved this issue in the past in similar way, I however do not know why that solved the issue.

eg:-

```
class GroupController{
    def save(){
      new GroupHandler().handleSave();
    }
  }
    
@CurrentTenant
class GroupHandler{
    
  def groupService // initialize service bean here 
  def handleSave(){
       groupService.getMember()
       groupService.updateMember()
    }
    
}
```